# Decode UID from dhcpd.leases

Tags: dhcp-server, mac-address, isc-dhcp, uid

I have am testing a device on my network which has this lease assigned:

```
lease 192.168.110.85 {
  starts 3 2022/07/20 16:12:37;
  ends 3 2022/07/20 16:22:37;
  cltt 3 2022/07/20 16:12:37;
  binding state active;
  next binding state free;
  rewind binding state free;
  hardware ethernet a4:06:e9:10:95:64;
  uid "\001\244\006\351\020\225d";
}
```

The device is not functioning well on the production network. I am trying get any information I can.

But I cannot decode the UID "\001\244\006\351\020\225d".

According to the DHCP manual this should be a hex string, other sources state it is octal (which it isn't). If it is a hex string, how should I interpret the bytes?

The DHCP server is isc-dhcp running on a linux platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it generally really makes sense to "decode" a UID value sent by a client, as the client may choose a UID that doesn't decode in any meaningful sense.

I do believe you are in luck, though, because the suggestion in the [manual](https://kb.isc.org/docs/isc-dhcp-44-manual-pages-dhcpdleases) (see the uid section) seems to match what you have in your example:

> uid client-identifier;
>
> The uid statement records the client identifier used by the client to
> acquire the lease. Clients are not required to send client
> identifiers, and this statement only appears if the client did in fact
> send one. **Client identifiers are normally an ARP type (1 for ethernet)
> followed by the MAC address,** just like in the hardware statement, but
> this is not required.
>
> The client identifier is **recorded as a colon-separated hexadecimal
> list or as a quoted string**. **If it is recorded as a quoted string and
> it contains one or more non-printable characters, those characters are
> represented as octal escapes - a backslash character followed by three
> octal digits**. The format used is determined by the lease-id-format
> parameter, which defaults to octal.

(emphasis added)

Looking at your value `"\001\244\006\351\020\225d"`, it's clearly the quoted string variation of value, and most bytes are escaped.

| input byte | hexadecimal | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| \001 | 01 | Ethernet |
| \244 | A4 |  |
| \006 | 06 |  |
| \351 | E9 |  |
| \020 | 10 |  |
| \225 | 95 |  |
| d | 64 | (reference your favorite ascii table) |

Which perfectly matches `hardware ethernet a4:06:e9:10:95:64`

Comment: I think I forgot how to convert octal to hex. And \225d put me on the wrong foot as well.

Comment: I makes perfect sense. The MAC label on the case says 00:D0:12:xx:xx:xx. Which is plain incorrect. In my DHCP lease I see it is something different and the device even identifies itself again with this value. So the manufacturer is messing around